# Merging files by Partition

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a Spark program that merges two files. When the files are small it all works fine. I run into problems when one file is HUGE. It either runs into issues with resources or takes a long time.

The HUGE file contains data for last 15 years, but the new data (small file) is only for last couple of years. Ideally, if I can partition my data by year & then merge new data only for the last couple of years that would speed up things a LOT!

How do I do this in Spark? As a side note, in the MapReduce world, I used to use MultipleOutputs class to accomplish this.

Comment: When you say merge, you mean creating a new file with the entire data? This operation would be serially executed and the huge file is just contributing "hugely" to this flow. If you want partitioned data (HDFS) the huge file with not behave much different than any other file with size of min split size (64-128MB). My guess is this

Answer (score 0):

You need partitionBy() from PairRDDFunctions (https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html). Get the year out as key before calling partitionBy with HashPartitioner argument. Now when you call join on first dataset, spark will remember that it is hash partitioned, so only the second dataset will be shuffled across the network to the corresponding partitions saving you loads of time. This works like MultipleOutputs by repartitioning your data based on key.